Problem With Jupyter and Visual Studio Code
I just keep receiving this error: Failed to start the Kernel:
Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpw8fxpxar\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73). 
View Jupyter log for further details.

I have tried absolutely everything, install Jupyter again, install Pyzmq, change the virtual environment, but it doesn't change.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I was facing the same error for 2 days, but I just found someone who helped here: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1981
Basically, run the following 2 lines on your cmd:
python -m pip uninstall pyzmq

pip install pyzmq==25.1.2

